# Changing End effector in realtime in moveit

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I am using UR5 robot with some custom end effector which obviously works good.Now my requirement is I need to change end effector in run time while move group is running which means URDF which is loaded as robot_description on ros param server is to be changed to other URDF which consist of my second gripper.Also I need to change semantic description on ros param server.Anybody has worked in such scnerio or can help me regarding this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270954/changing-end-effector-in-realtime-in-moveit/) by [akash_p](https://answers.ros.org/users/30666/akash_p/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-09-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matEhickey](https://answers.ros.org/users/31791/matehickey/) on 2017-10-10**:
Hello, I'm exactly in the same situation, did you manage to find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yup.I found a workaround to solve this issue not a complete solution though.Following are the steps.

1.Load robot_description to rosparam server with urdf consisting of 1st end effector.

2.Whenever you want to switch to new end effector replace robot_descritption on rosparam server by reading data from URDF of new end effector with complete robot and also replace robot_description_semantic on rosparam server by new srdf file corrosponding to your new URDF.

3.Now I am doing all this replacing through my cpp node and then using system() function to kill move_group node,robot_description node and rviz_node.(Remember to set respawn=true for all these nodes in your corresponding moveit package launch files).

4.All the killed nodes will respawn now and will load my newly uploaded robot_description and robot_description_semantic from rosparam server and in rviz you will be able to visualize your new end effector.

Since moveit move_group node spawns up moveit_planning_scene service once at the start and it loads robot_description only once at start we need to respawn all the nodes to take up our new robot URDF and its corresponding semantic description.Hope this helps you!

---

Originally posted by [akash_p](https://answers.ros.org/users/30666/akash_p/) with karma: 26 on 2017-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matEhickey](https://answers.ros.org/users/31791/matehickey/) on 2017-10-10**:
Thank you, well played for this solution, I will try to implement this for my needs !

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
A note of caution: this isn't really a solution, but more of a work-around, and, as you're only restarting *some* of the consumers of those parameters/artefacts, you run the risk of ending up with a 'desynced' ROS node graph, in which some participants are using one version of `robot_description` ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
.. and related parameters, and others another. In controlled environments this probably won't be a big problem, but I wanted to note it (for future readers) in any case.

The real problem here is the immutability of `robot_description`, and the fact that none of its current consumers are set up ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
.. to deal with changes to that parameter.

Also note: there are multiple ways to parse urdfs (raw xml, `urdf_dom`, custom parsers, etc), and many nodes even use a combination of those different ways at the same time. This all makes "changing EEFs in 'real-time'" a rather complex piece of ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
.. functionality to implement. Much more complex than a lot of people assume.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
Finally: some alternative work-arounds:

1. if the EEF doesn't require any control (based on URDF, that is): use MoveIt's *attached collision object* infrastructure for your gripper. Those can be attached and detached at runtime without the earlier mentioned complications (although it will be ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
.. MoveIt-specific)

2 . run two `move_group` instances in parallel. Namespaced and each with their own `robot_description` and related parameters.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
@akash_p wrote:

> but move_group loads robot_description only at start was my main concern

as it should: `robot_description` is a parameter, and those are only intended to be read in a node's initialisation phase.

That is why having `robot_description` being a parameter is such a limitation.

**Comment by [akash_p](https://answers.ros.org/users/30666/akash_p/) on 2017-10-10**:
True I do understand this is workaround and not solution.I cannot use my second end effector as attached collision object since I need to actually attach object to my second end effector in real time.Regarding your second solution in order to keep unique moveit application I kept things simple.

**Comment by [akash_p](https://answers.ros.org/users/30666/akash_p/) on 2017-10-10**:
But it can be tried using multiple moveit instances with multiple robot_description

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:\

> .I cannot use my second eef as attached collision object [..] I need to actually attach object to my second eef

as far as I know there is no limit to the nr of attached objects. So you should be able to attach the eef and the objects.

**Comment by [akash_p](https://answers.ros.org/users/30666/akash_p/) on 2017-10-10**:
One more issue was my second end effector has a joint which is active joint in moveit package which cant be emulated in an attached collision object.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
No. As I wrote above: work-around 1 only works if your EEF doesn't need to be controlled by MoveIt (fi: if it's a simple open/close gripper with its own controller).

A work-around for that might be to have two different 'versions' of your EEF 'collision object': one closed, the other open. But ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
.. again: that will not be much help if your gripper needs to be controlled by MoveIt.

**Comment by [akash_p](https://answers.ros.org/users/30666/akash_p/) on 2017-10-10**:
My joint is not like fingered gripper like just fully open and fully closed,its revolute joint rotating in semi circular +/- 180 degree so its really hard for me to save orientation of each of the degree as collision object so I discarded this option since this was suggestion by many people on forum

**Comment by [akash_p](https://answers.ros.org/users/30666/akash_p/) on 2017-10-10**:
@gvdhoorn For your second solution how will my multiple moveit instances behave to real single robot controller and its feedback in the form of joint states?Wont it go much complex?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-10-10**:
It will take some careful topic remapping and namespacing, but it should be possible.